# dojo.connect not working in IE but sometimes in chrome&firefox

Tags: internet-explorer-8, onclick, dojo

I finally got some parts working here: http://jsfiddle.net/trXBr/5/
but when I put the code back into my project and tried to browse using internet explorer; the button onclick events do not work. Interestingly the one button onclick function to show the dialog works in firefox and chrome. I was excited to have this working in the editor but now if this does not work with all browsers, then this is just really frustrating. I am using version 1.5.1

```
         dojo.connect(loadBtn,'onClick',function(){ 
                userDialog.show(); 
              });   

        dojo.connect(butt,'onClick',function(evt){ 
               showTab(); 
        });
```

Any help/ideas appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok using the compatibility mode in IE helps to get the one function working which displays the dialog box.

So as you can see here I have an borderlayout where I want a tabcontainer to be displayed in the middle with a click of a button and this works fine in jsfiddler but not from my code in the browsers;

```
 <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" splitter="true">
  <div id="mainTabContainer"dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer"
           style="width:500px;height:100px;display:none">
      <div id="tab1" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
       title="First Tab" selected="true" 
         closable="true">First Tab</div>
     <div id="tab2" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
      title="Second Tab" closable="true">
       Second Tab
     </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

so the display:none but when I click the button I call the following:

```
dojo.connect(butt,'onClick',function(evt){ 
               showTab(); 
}); 
function showTab(){
         dijit.byId("mainTabContainer").domNode.style.display = 'block'
         dijit.byId("mainTabContainer").resize();
   }
```

Also if I remove the display=none then the tabcontainer appears fine.  So is these something wrong with my function call.

Comment: Any reason for why you are using an old version of Dojo?

Comment: The example code you liked to is to big for us to easily figure what is going on. Try to demonstrate your problem with the smallest ammount of code possible.

Comment: The relevant bit of the example code is quoted in the question.  But the sample linked to works for me in IE9 and IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode.  What's the problem that you see?

Comment: I do not understand version 1.7 yet so I have been experimenting; ok when I used the compatibility view then one of the functions worked which displayed the dialog box but still the one that displays the tabcontainer does not. Someone else suggested I change the version to 1.6 and did that but still nothing. I will edit my post and add some code.

Comment: By the way, is this actually a different question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486473/create-a-dojo-tabcontainer-dynamically-by-button-click?  Does this one replace that one?

Comment: oh yes sorry abt that forgot abt that question...I actually posed that question when it did not work in jsfiddler where I did my testing so I should scrap that question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok sorry guys....all my fault here...I forgot to remove the added code I had in my html in my asp.net code

```
<body class="claro">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Once I removed the form and scriptmanager lines it works fine..Thanks for everyones efforts.
Just worried that if I were to incorporate ajax and other controls, then would dojo still work